# How do I redirect a website with a specified referrer like Facebook? HTML

Tags: html, redirect, referrer

I have my own blog website but I would like to have it redirect to another website with a referrer like Facebook. Is it possible that this can happen? Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but the user will have to go to Facebook first because your link will start with the facebook domain

Like the link below, it is supposed to take you to google.com but make it appear like you came from Facebook:
https://facebook.com/l.php?u=https://www.google.com

But you realize you have to visit Facebook first then it throws a warning